# UITableViewCell style and dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I register my cell:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // setting up the cell
}
```

The issue is I can't set the `cell.detailTextLabel.text` property. The cell is never `nil`.

Comment: Any error message? Are you using IB or storyboard?

Comment: No errors. Just no text in the detailedTextLabel.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If called first, table view `registerClass` will cause `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to return non-nil cell if the cell reuse identifier matches.

I believe registerClass is generally used for cells that will be a custom cell derived from `UITableViewCell`.  Your custom cell can overrite initWithStyle and set the style there.

It's not always necessary to create a custom cell.

If you want to set the cell style then don't call `registerClass`.

Comment: Yep, not registering the class did it. Thanks.

Comment: Not registering the class throws `NSInternalInconsistencyException`. "reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier FileLogCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'"

Comment: Fix for @RahulJiresal 's problem is to make sure you use `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"]` and NOT `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath]`

Answer (score 15):

you need do followed 3 changes to achieve you goal:

1. remove registerClass statement.
2. UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   => UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
3. use initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

usually there are two ways to create cell with subtile, firstly with custom UITableViewCell, set style in the init. secondly with followed code, which is what you wanted:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the storyboard, and set the cell style in IB. In that case, you shouldn't register anything, nor should you have an if (cell == nil) clause. It doesn't seem to matter whether you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: or dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath. They both are guaranteed to return a cell when that cell is created in the storyboard.

Comment: I don't prefer to us IB, haven't really used it a lot and preferred to stay all in code. I do need to get more familiar with using IB though. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom cell. Change its style in interface builder. Use table view register the cell from nib your view controller.

[image: Set the style]

And the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:kReuseIdentifier];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kReuseIdentifier];

    // Do things with the cell. 
    // The cell has no chance to be nil because you've already registered it in viewDidLoad method. 
    // So there's not need to write any code like if(cell==nil).
    // Just use it.

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle style for the cell. Change the line in the if statement to this:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: the statement inside the if is not executed at all

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the cell style:

```
if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

to this

```
if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
```

This will work for you.

Comment: Once I removed the registering the cell, the cell was nil and did get initialized. And I did need to change the cell style, thanks.

Comment: The rest code remain same you just need to change the cell style.

Comment: the statement inside the if is not executed at all

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question. I just want to provide a alternative solution.

Why not try below, after you register the cell:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

then do:

```
[cell initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
```

It works for me.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was -1 and so far down. This should be the accepted solution.